# A die is weighted so that each even number is twice as likely to appear as any odd number.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

[image]

> 3.32. A die is weighted so that the even numbers have the same chance of appearing, the odd numbers have the same chance of appearing, and each even number is twice as likely to appear as any odd number. Find the probability that $(\mathrm{i})$ an even number appears,
> (ii) a prime number appears,
> (iii) an odd number appears, (iv) an odd prime number appears.

**My attempted solution of $(ii)$**

$P($an odd number$) = \frac{1}{9}$
$P($an even number$) = \frac{2}{9}$
$P($all prime numbers$)=P(1, 2, 3, 5) = (\frac{1}{9}+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}) = \frac{5}{9}$

[image]

**The given answer is $\frac{4}{9}$**.

Why is that?

Comment: $1$ is not a prime number.

Comment: hmmmm.....didn't know that.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number ... (just saw thet nicomezi already said that)

Comment: @yahoo.com: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i)$ Since even numbers are twice as likely to appear as any odd numbers.

[image]
Probability that even number appears $$=\frac29+\frac29+\frac29=\frac69$$
$$=\frac23$$

Note that in a die {$1,2,3,4,5,6$}, **Prime**$=${$2,3,5$},**Non-Prime**$=${$1,4,6$}

$ii)$Probability that a prime number appears$$=\frac29+\frac19+\frac19=\frac49$$

$iii)$Probability that odd number appears$$=\frac39 =\frac13$$

$iv)$Probability that an odd prime number appears $(3,5)$

$$=\frac19+\frac19=\frac29$$